# How does windbg classify crashes broadly and which term in result of "!analyze -v" indicates this?

Tags: windbg

Can you give me details of all the terms that are useful to understand properly the issue with crash after we use "!analyze -v"? Which term indicates what like The FAULTING_IP field shows the instruction pointer at the time of the fault.

I am not getting it anywhere with proper description.

Comment: "of all the terms" is a bit broad for a question. I'm trying to make sense of `!analyze -v` for 10 years now, and I still understand only ~30%. When clients called me for crash analysis, I requested the output of `!analyze -v` and then decided whether I could perhaps help or I better rejected the task. There are so many possibilities... In all the cases where I was hired, someone explained the application to me (not on source code level, though).

Comment: `!analyze` has 100.000+ lines of code, implements 500+ heuristics and can create more than 25.000.000+ buckets. I'm not sure how different the output can get.

Answer (score 1):

It is `BUCKET_ID` that categorizes the issue, and Microsoft has a big internal database to reveal typical issues,

> The BUCKET_ID field shows the specific category of failures that the current failure belongs to. This category helps the debugger determine what other information to display in the analysis output.
>
> If you are connected to the internet, the debugger attempts to access a database of crash solutions maintained by Microsoft. This database contains links to a tremendous number of Web pages that have information about known bugs. If a match is found for your problem, the INTERNAL_SOLUTION_TEXT field will show a URL that you can access for more information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-the--analyze-extension

If you need to investigate on non typical issues, things like `STACK_COMMAND` might be your friend.

However, dump analysis on native crashes is never an easy task, and corrupt memory can further mess up the situation.

So you should buy services from either Microsoft or other service providers.

Comment: I was trying to make an standalone library that would assist in identifying right bucketing of existing crashes I have collected some exceptions on that basis I was trying to make library. Trying to make tool over windbg kind of so that makind easy to analyze 100s of crash dump.

Comment: @Prachi I commented on your other question on what you should look for. WinDbg is a black box so you should walk further on this path.